# Importing a matrix to python

Tags: python, numpy, import

I have a huge matrix in notepad. I want to import it in python for some calculation. What is the easiest way? 
This is a pic of a part of matrix:[image]

As i know I have to change it to the following format which doing that manually is very hard. Is there any other way?

```
cm=[[ 9.37616521e-01,   0.00000000e+00,   2.72479564e-03,   9.03484870e-03
      3.58525742e-03  , 4.70385774e-02]],
   [[ 0.00000000e+00  , 6.55069086e-01  , 3.31946063e-01 ,  2.16414183e-03
      8.49009489e-03 ,  2.33061428e-03]]]
```

Comment: Why is that very hard?  some find/replace should do the trick, no?

Comment: or a basic use of readline() and split() will work too

Comment: Read the file by line and for every line do something like `[float(i) for i in line.strip('[] ').split()]`

Comment: That is a set of nested lists, not a numpy array. It would be simpler to load the data directly into a numpy array using  [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).